# Sort header not working with data from angular service

Tags: angular, sorting, html-table, observable, angular-material2

I try to implement a vary basic table (date, weight) with [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview).

The sort is already implemented with "MatSort" and works great for me (see official example [here](https://stackblitz.com/angular/voqnaoexppp?file=app%2Ftable-sorting-example.ts)).

Now i want to retrieve data from an HTTP request GET, with an angular service returning Observables. It's works for filling data table but sort is not working anymore, no arrows on the headers...

**weight.component.ts**

```
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Weight>();

  constructor(
    private _weightsService: WeightsService,
  ) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this._weightsService.getWeights().subscribe(data => {
      this.dataSource.data = data;
      this.dataSource.data = this.dataSource.data;
    });
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }
```

**weight.component.html**

```
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
      <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
      <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></mat-row>
      <!-- Date Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="date">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Date </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.date | amDateFormat:'DD/MM/YYYY'}} </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
      <!-- Weight Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Poids </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.weight}} </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
</mat-table>
```

**weight.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class WeightsService {
  constructor(private _httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  getWeights(): Observable<Weight[]> {
    return this._httpClient.get<Weight[]>(URI).map(results => {
      results.forEach(weight => (weight.date = moment(weight.date)));
      return results;
    });
}
```

**weight.ts**

```
import * as moment from 'moment';

export class Weight {
  constructor(public id: number, public date: moment.Moment, public weight: number) {}
}
```

I already try to move the sort line inside the subscribe of the data but it's not working neither.

I don't understand how to retrieve data from HTTP and having the sort working ! I have seen than i can make a new class implementing DateSource, connect(), disconnect() and re-rewrite sorting...([see here](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-material-data-table/)). But i'm not sure i need that since i don't want to override sorting.

Thanks you in advance for your help !

Comment: please provide your code.

Comment: see updated post

Answer (score 2):

Finally the problem was the missing :

```
import { MatSortModule } from '@angular/material';
```

I test some code on Stackblitz when i'm not at home, and retrieve some code when i come back, but i forgot to do this import... And the use of MatSort without importing it doesn't throw an error !

I open an issue for this ([#11079](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/11079)) on angular/material2.